# requests.Session() creating different session every time. How to reuse it?

Tags: python, request, session-cookies

I am trying to initialize a `requests.Session`, to keep a connection with a webpage. However, I read that each time the session class is called, a new session is created.

How is it possible to keep the connection alive? Because with my current code, it's giving me the webpage content after I call the `login` method (that's OK, it shows that I logged into the page and gives me the content I want), but when I call the `update` method, it gives me the content from the login page again, not from the page I actually want after login.

```py
import requests

class LoginLogout:

    # creating session
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = requests.Session()

    # login method
    def login(self, user, password, server):
        payload_data = {'user': user, 'pass': password, 'server': server}
        print(self.s.post(LOGIN_LINK, payload_data))

    # update method
    def update(self, updt_link):
        print(self.s.get(updt_link))

    def logout(self):
        response = self.s.get('...some webpage/user/logout...')
        self.s.close()
        print(response)
```

Here I am calling the objects:

```py
if switch_parameter == "login":
    login_var = LoginLogout()
    login_var.login(USER, PASSWORD, SERVER)
    print('IS IT OK ?', login_var.s.get('.../login...'))  # <-OK it shows 200 result (but should I use there "s" too ?)
elif switch_parameter == "start":
    start()
elif switch_parameter == "stop":
    stop()
elif switch_parameter == "update":
    update_prem = LoginLogout()
    update_prem.update('...different/page...')
    # (am I missing here "s" ?, or I shouldnt be using it here anyway)
elif switch_parameter == "logout":
    logout()
else:
    pass
```

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to use `login` to log into the website and keep the session active, while calling `update` every time I need to get another page. Am I even on the right track or completely wrong?

Comment: is the second code in a while loop ? Please share the exact code you have

Comment: Hi, no it is not in the loop. I will call this python from the .php file when I need with: exec("/usr/bin/python3.6 /var/www/html/AutoBot/py_functions/functionality.py 2>&1 '$param' ", $output); This part works ok. thanks

Comment: If the $param is update, it will call update part, if the $param is login, login part is called, etc.

Comment: And how do you expect session attributes to carry over between two distinct executions of your Python script? In other words: You don't actually believe that when you start a new Python process with the `update` parameter, it will magically have access to cookies created in some previous Python process that was called with the `login` parameter, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of `requests.Session` is to persist ephemeral constants (like cookies) between requests. In your code you initialize a new session object, when you initialize a `LoginLogout` object.

You do that here:

```py
if switch_parameter == "login":        
    login_var = LoginLogout()
...
```

And you do that here:

```py
elif switch_parameter == "update":
    update_prem = LoginLogout()
...
```

Now `login_var` and `update_prem` are obviously different objects and both have the `s` attribute, each holding a different `requests.Session` object. How do you expect the attributes of one session to be magically available to the other?

If you want to use an existing session, use it. Don't create a new one.

I don't know about your actual use case of course, but from what you have presented here, it seems you need to do something like this:

```py
scraper_obj = LoginLogout()
scraper_obj.login(USER, PASSWORD, SERVER)
...
scraper_obj.update('...')
...
scraper_obj.logout()
```

Since your created a wrapper around the actual `requests.Session` instance with `LoginLogout`, you should not ever need to deal with its `s` attribute directly, assuming you have methods on `LoginLogout` for every kind of request you want to make. You initialize it once and then use its methods to perform requests via its internal session object.

---

#### PS

You casually mentioned in a follow-up comment that you set this up as a script to be called repeatedly from the outside and depending on the parameter passed to the script, you want to either log into the site or scrape a specific page.

This shows that you either don't understand how "logging in" even works or that you don't understand how processes work. Typically some session attribute (e.g. cookie) is created on the client so that it can present it to the server to show that it is already authenticated. When using `requests` as an HTTP client library, this data is stored inside a `requests.Session` object.

When you call a Python script, you create a new process. Just because you start the same script twice in a row does not mean that one of those processes has **any** connection to the other. Calling the script to login once has **absolutely no effect** on what happens the next time you call that script to do something else. None of those earlier session attributes will be present in the second process. I hope this is clear now.

Comment: Aaah, so most probably it needs to be inside the loop, to keep it persistent. Hmm. Then I cannot call the python script with parameter when I need. damn. It will be new session every time. What crap did I code, aaah. I need to come up with different approach. Thanks DF

Comment: Hi, to be honest, my brain completely ignored the part that python script is freshly called so no previous attributes will be used. And tbh2, I started with coding couple weeks ago so still beginner here :). Anyway thanks for all your support.

Comment: @BedSon No worries. Starting out doing silly things is normal. Often times, returning to the fundamentals, even though it can be dry and boring, really helps to clarify and cut through the fuzzyness/nonsense found online, which is why I pointed out your seeming lack of understanding of either HTTP or system processes, so as to nudge you towards the literature on those topics.

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty boring to just read the books. And now I'm just stuck on like page 200  and cannot go further. I wanted to try few things I read and make this learning more interesting, but the sessions and similar stuff is not part of the book. So went through some YT videos, and apparently still big road ahead of me.